# OnDestroy android studio

Tags: android

Sempre que desse um erro no android no código não deveria chamar o onDestroy? Pq pelo que eu vi aqui ele chama o onDestroy só quando é usado quando utilizar finish().. correto? Pq caso ocorre-se um erro queria salvar as ações do usuário antes de fechar completamente

Comment: onDestroy é chamado quando o ciclo de vida de uma activity se encerra, quando se pressiona o botão voltar é chamado onBackPressed() https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity

Comment: Ajudo nada.. mais vlw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Sempre que desse um erro no android no código não deveria chamar o onDestroy?"

Não, não há garantias que o sistema sempre chame o onDestroy, quando precisar liberar recursos ou quando alguém der um kill -9 em você, por exemplo.

> #### void onDestroy()
>
> "Executa qualquer limpeza final antes que uma atividade seja destruída. Isso pode acontecer porque a activity está terminando, ou porque o sistema está temporariamente destruindo essa instância da activity para economizar espaço [...]
>   *Há situações em que o sistema simplesmente mata o processo que hospeda a activity **sem chamar esse método (ou qualquer outro)**, portanto não deve ser usado para fazer as coisas que devem permanecer após o processo desaparecer.*"

> "Pq caso ocorre-se um erro queria salvar as ações do usuário antes de fechar completamente"

Se é esse o seu objetivo então configure um `UncaughtExceptionHandler`, coloque na primeira instância de activity do seu aplicativo:

```
Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler oldHandler = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
    @Override
    public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable exception) {
        // Lide com o erro aqui
    }
    if (oldHandler != null)
       oldHandler.uncaughtException(thread, exception);
    else
       System.exit(2);
    }
});
```

Você pode querer colocar esse código em mais de uma activity para tentar manusear erros de forma diferente, não recomendo, se o fizer, esse mesmo código será executado mais de uma vez e ao mesmo tempo no caso de um crash.

[Referência](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427515/using-global-exception-handling-on-android/#26560727)

Comment: Se funcionar em uma activity já perfeito... vlw caraaaaa